# Pandas Key Error When Searching For Keyword In "Cell"

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I am iterating over some data in a pandas dataframe searching for specific keywords, however the resulting regex search results in a KeyError: 19.

I've tried to pull out the data in the specific cell, place it in a string object and search through that, but every time I attempt to point anything to look a the data in that column, I get a KeyError: 19.

To preface my code example, I have pulled out specific chunks of the dataframe and placed them in a list of lists. (Of these chunks, I have kept all of the columns that were in the original dataframe)

Here is an example of the iteration I am attempting:

```
for eachGroup in mainList:
   for lineItem in eachGroup:
      if re.search(r'( keyword )', lineItem[19], re.I):
         dostuff
```

As you might have guessed, the data I am searching for keywords in is column 19 which has data formatted like this:

```
 3/23/2019 11:32:0 3/23/2019 11:32:0 3/23/2019 14:3:0 CSG CHG H6   27   1464D  Random Random Random  81
```

Every other attempt at searching for keywords in different columns executes fine without any errors. Why would this case alone return a KeyError?

To add some more clarity, even the following code produces the same KeyError:

```
for eachGroup in mainList:
   for lineItem in eachGroup:
      text = lineItem[19]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a WTF moment...

Instead of using python's smart `for` looping, I decided to be more granular and loop through with a `while` loop. Needless to say it worked.

The below code implementation fixes the issue though ***why*** it does I have no clue:

```
bigCount = len(mainList)
count = 0
while count < bigCount:
   while smallCount < len(mainList[count]):
      if re.search(r'( keyword )', mainList[count][smallCount][19], re.I):
         dostuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `re.search(r'( keyword )', lineItem[19], re.I):` to `re.match('(.*)keyword(.*)', lineItem[19]):`. `re.search` will return the corresponding matching object, while `re.match` will return a logical value that you need in an if statement. The suffix and prefix `(.*)` is to ignore any other character to the left or right of the string. Hope it helps.

Comment: While I thank you for the regex advise, the error has to do with "lineItem[19]" as I have even tried setting a string = lineItem[19]. This too results in the same KeyError.